# HTML Multiple columns in multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, multiple-columns

I want to display a webpage in a book-like fashion, with two columns, spread through several pages.

I am using **column-count**, which works fine for one page, but I need to split the text after a certain number of lines to display the rest in a new page.

So instead of displaying the text as:

> A B C D E... (each letter represents a column of text)

I want:

> A B
>  C D
>  E..

Ho to do this, specifying the number of lines per page to be displayed (and the number of columns, although in my case it will always be 2) and  automatically arrange it with Javascript?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot, each space is also rendered as a column!

However, you cannot use CSS for that to break the line at each character, either you will use

```
max-width: 5px; /* approximately one char */
```

or you'll use jQuery to break the string at each character and then write it appending `<br />` to the line.

```
var chars = "A B C D E F";
charArray = chars.split(" "); /* at white space */
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
   /* write it and then add <br /> at the end */
}
```

This way you can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a table, it's really simple.

```
<table style="border: 0px">
<tr>
<td><!-- First column --></td>
<td><!-- Second column --></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for. It's Adam Wulf's jQuery **columnizer** plugin (http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/). He provides several examples, and the newsletter sample (http://welcome.totheinter.net/autocolumn/sample10.html) shows just what I was looking for. It works beautifully on all browsers I tried.

Thanks for the replies. They are not exactly what I wanted, because the content I have to split into columns is not just a string, but a series of HTML elements. Further, it is not static, so manually splitting it into tables is not an option.

Comment: Further to my solution above, I want to comment that in IE8 sometimes it doesn't work at first. What I did was to click on Tools>Developer Tools>Script>Console, and then it works fine. No need to change anything, just opening the console solves the problem, although I don't know why this works.